# GCH and cardinal exponentiation and Aleph numbers

Tags: set-theory

How does the GCH make cardinal exponentially easier I am reading set theory in metric spaces by Kaplansky  and I can’t see that

Comment: Do you know the statement of GCH?

Comment: Yah ,it was v mysterious to me

Comment: Well, it says that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for every ordinal $\alpha$. So it is a statement about cardinal exponentiation, and it should not be surprising that having extra assumptions like that makes calculating these things easier. Alessandro has typed out a good answer outlining how exactly it becomes easier.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\gimel(\kappa)=\kappa^{\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)}$ be the Gimel function. We have that $\kappa^\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal is determined as follows:

- $0^\lambda=0, 1^\lambda=1$.
- For $2\leq\kappa\leq\lambda$, $\kappa^\lambda=2^\lambda$.
- If $\kappa>\lambda$ and there exist $\xi<\kappa$ with $\xi^\lambda\geq\kappa$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\xi^\lambda$.
- If $\kappa>\lambda$, $\xi^\lambda<\kappa$ for $\xi<\kappa$ and $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)>\lambda$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa$.
- If $\kappa>\lambda$, $\xi^\lambda<\kappa$ for $\xi<\kappa$ and $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)\leq\lambda$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\gimel(\kappa)$.

However assuming $\mathsf{GCH}$ computing $\kappa^\lambda$ is much easier, as follows:

- If $\lambda<\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa$.
- If $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)\leq\lambda\leq\kappa$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa^+$.
- If $\lambda>\kappa$, then $\kappa^\lambda=\lambda^+$.

The point is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ places very little restrictions on the behaviour of cardinal exponentiations, while $\mathsf{GCH}$ is, on the other hand, a very strong restriction.

Comment: How come my question gets -2